Username Case Sensitive Problem Of Subversion(SVN)
Environment
I'm using Subversion(1.14.1) and Ubuntu(22.04.4 LTS) as the server, TortoiseSVN(1.14.7) as the client.
Case
【Case1】
Yesterday, I have no user group on svn server. My passwd and authz files are like:
[users]
User1=password1
User2=password2
User3=password3

[groups]
# empty

[/]
* = rw

At that time, I can log in svn from client by both Username=User1 and Username=user1, which is case insensitive.
【Case2】
Today, I add some groups to svn server. My passwd and authz files are like:
[users]
User1=password1
User2=password2
User3=password3

[groups]
Group1 = User1,User2
Group2 = User3


[/]
@Group1 = rw
* = 

Now, I can log in svn from client only by Username=User1. Username=user1 fails, which is case sensitive.
Question
This is very wired to me.
I changed no setting on Subversion, but Subversion changes its behavior on case sensitive for username.
Besides, I don't know this problem is caused by the server or the client.

As far as I know, the username is ALWAYS case sensitive.
That said, in [Case 1] ALL users have access. The server in that case wouldn't even ask for authentication and TortoiseSVN shouldn't even ask for a username. If you used the command line client you can specify a username and password using the --username and --password options, but these are only sent to the server if it asks for authentication so in that case it would look like you authenticated with "user1" although it wasn't so.

--Long Reply Start--

Thanks. But I think "SVN wouldn't even ask for authentication" is not due to "[/] * = rw" in authz file, but due to "anon-access = write" in svnserve.conf file.

svnserve.conf file deals with how svn treats anonymous user and authenticated user. If "anon-access = write" in svnserve.conf, SVN will even ask for authentication for anonymous user. But if "anon-access = none", SVN will ask for authentication.

authz file deals with authenticated user only. "* = rw" in authz file doesn't mean any user(anonymous and authenticated) can read and write, it means any authenticated user can read and write.

I did some tests. While keeping "* = rw" in authz file, changes "anon-access = ?" in svnserve.conf file.

➊If "anon-access = write", SVN will not ask for authentication at "svn update" or "svn commit". Anonymous user can update and commit.
➋If "anon-access = read", SVN will not ask for authentication at "svn update", but it will ask for authentication at "svn commit". Anonymous user can not commit.
➌If "anon-access = none", SVN will ask for authentication at "svn update" and "svn commit". Anonymous user can not commit nor update.

As for 【Case1】, I have "anon-access = none" in svnserve.conf. So "user1" was authenticated at that case.

--Long Reply End--

I tried command line. For 【Case1】and 【Case2】, the outcome is the same as using TortoiseSVN. So this case sensitive problem is not caused by TortoiseSVN.

This time, I find that the error message is different. For 【Case2】, if I use a totally wrong username and password, the error message is "Username not found" or "Password incorrect". But if I use a case sensitive wrong username, the error message is "Authorization failed"
